# ms bot framework onMembersAddedActivity does not get invoked using nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

i am using nodejs google cloud functions with ms bot framework. I have the invoke code looks like below:

```
const BotFrameworkAdapter = require('botbuilder').BotFrameworkAdapter
const { TeamsConversationBot } = require('./flashmsteamsbot');

const msadapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: 'XXX',
    appPassword: 'XXX'
});

const msteamsbot = new TeamsConversationBot()

const app = express();
app.post('/api/messages', (req:any, res:any) => {
    msadapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context:any) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
       await msteamsbot.run(context)
    });
});
```

the teams class looks like below:

```
const {
    TurnContext,
    TeamsActivityHandler,
    CardFactory,
    AttachmentLayoutTypes,
    ActionTypes
} = require('botbuilder');

class TeamsConversationBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onMessage(async (context:any, next:any) => {
            TurnContext.removeRecipientMention(context.activity);
            
            let msg = context.activity.text
            const senderId = context.activity.from.aadObjectId 
           
            switch (msg) {
                case 'don1': 
                        await this.don1(context, keyword.trim(), userKey)
                        break;
                default:
                            await this.help(context)
                            break;
            }
            await next();
        });

        this.onMembersAddedActivity(async (context:any, next:any) => {
            functions.logger.log("start of onMembersAddedActivity", context)
            context.activity.membersAdded.forEach(async (teamMember:any) => {
                if (teamMember.id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    await context.sendActivity(`Welcome to the team ${ teamMember.givenName } ${ teamMember.surname }`);
                }
            });
            await next();
        });
    }
```

Whenever i send a message to the bot the this.onMessage is getting invoked. However, when i add a new member to a group where my bot is already present, the onMembersAddedActivity is not invoked. what i am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is partially [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/2897) in our docs and code comments, which I addressed [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs-pr/pull/2441) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/2902), respectively. The other issue is that you're using `<method>Activity()` instead of `<method>Event()`.

The latest instructions are in the [code comments](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder/src/teamsActivityHandler.ts#L35), which just got merged, but basically,

> Developers may handle Conversation Update activities sent from Microsoft Teams via two methods:
>
> 1. Overriding methods starting with `on..` and *not* ending in `..Event()` (e.g. `onTeamsMembersAdded()`), or instead
> 2. Passing callbacks to methods starting with `on..` *and* ending in `...Event()` (e.g. `onTeamsMembersAddedEvent()`),
>    to stay in line with older {@link ActivityHandler} implementation.

> Developers should use either #1 or #2, above for all Conversation Update activities and not *both* #2 and #3 for the same activity. Meaning,
> developers should override `onTeamsMembersAdded()` and not use both `onTeamsMembersAdded()` and `onTeamsMembersAddedEvent()`.

> Developers wanting to handle Invoke activities *must* override methods starting with `handle...()` (e.g. `handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch()`).

So, for you, you can either:

```js
constructor() {
    [...]
    // This is passing in a callback
    this.onTeamsMembersAddedEvent(async (
            membersAdded: TeamsChannelAccount[],
            teamInfo: TeamInfo,
            context: TurnContext,
            next: () => Promise<void>) => {
        functions.logger.log("start of onMembersAddedActivity", context)
        context.activity.membersAdded.forEach(async (teamMember:any) => {
            if (teamMember.id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                await context.sendActivity(`Welcome to the team ${ teamMember.givenName } ${ teamMember.surname }`);
            }
        });
        await next();
    });
}
```

or

```js
constructor() {
    [...]
}

[...]

// This is an override
async onTeamsMembersAdded(context: TurnContext): Promise<void> {
    functions.logger.log("start of onMembersAddedActivity", context)
    context.activity.membersAdded.forEach(async (teamMember:any) => {
        if (teamMember.id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
            await context.sendActivity(`Welcome to the team ${ teamMember.givenName } ${ teamMember.surname }`);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i am now getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'membersAdded' of undefined

Comment: My mistake. I had the method signature for `onTeamsMembersAddedEvent()` wrong. See updated code.